# how to combine multiple curve Arrays into one single curve Array

Tags: c#, revit

I am new to create Revit plugin by C sharp . I have multiple curveArrays and i want to merge it into one single curveArray . I saw some posts regarding same issue but those were not curveArrays, rather integer or strings arrays.

Comment: Can you post code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: i tried but cannot add a picture . Basically I just require a code of how to add multiple curvearrays into one curvearray . The code is really bif and i tried to add picture here but couldnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CurveArray](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2015/55103aad-38fd-45d2-6bf7-67a5203e99f3.htm) is [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netframework-4.8), and it has an [Append()](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2015/8a9eabb9-9d6a-9c11-e4d2-c5a7d7f49168.htm) method.

Have you tried doing:

```
var allCurves = new CurveArray();

foreach (CurveArray curveArr in multipleCurveArrays)
{
    foreach (Curve curve in curveArr)
    {
        allCurves.Append(curve);
    }
}
```

Comment: hugo can you explain abit please .

Comment: `multipleCurveArrays` is a collection of the `CurveArray`s you want to combine, and this code adds all the curves of each  `CurveArray` to a new `CurveArray` called `allCurves`.
I don't know what else to say...
Try to clarify your question, or explain what you don't understand.

Comment: because when i enter this word multipleCurveArrays , its showing red line underneath . and where is my input of 5 curveArrays which i want to combine.

Comment: I have 5 curveArrays namely curArr1 , curArr2 , curArr3 , curArr4 , curArr5 , where should i feed them to get my final curveArray

Comment: Replace `multipleCurveArrays` with `new CurveArray[] { curArr1, curArr2, curArr3, curArr4, curArr5 }`

Comment: i have some other problem now but i think this problem is solved . Thanks alot for your help. I am feeding this final curveArray into foorprintroof creation method and still giving some problem.

Comment: You're welcome!
You have to post a separate question since it's another problem.
If you do, please post your code and anything relevant, else people won't be able to help you. Good luck!

Comment: how can i add screenshot etc to show you problem and code . i dont know actually . Thanks